# Редирект c конструктора Wix

Tags: редирект, http-status-code-301

столкнулась с проблемой редиректа сайта с WIX на Bitrix (если это важно).
Возникает вопрос, как сделать редирект со старого сайта на конструкторе на новый? Совет "просто погугли" не подойдет, так как все статьи объясняют, как наоборот сделать редиректы и переносы старого сайта на новый на wix.
Пробовала разобраться как-то внутри самого конструктора, но ничего нет, если и получается сделать редирект, то внутри самого сайта (т.е., например, со страницы /otzyvy на страницу /reviews).

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: С `wix` скорее всего никак. Если домен был ваш, то в `nginx`/`apache` конфиге указываете, что `/ovzyvy` теперь на `/reviews`. Это делается на новом сервере. Если был домен от `wix` (типа `sitename.wix.ru`) то скорее нельзя

Answer (score 0):

Чисто технически можно. Даже если домен принадлежит wix'y и нету серверного ЯП.

Вставить в код главного `js` файла, который выводится на всех страницах что-то типа:
`window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('https://domain.old', 'https://domain.new');`

Там можно и любую логику маршрутизации сотворить. Правила, заголовки и т.п.

А вот уже, как поисковики этот костыль схавают, и не обидится ли сам wix за такое, - вопрос открытый...